# Error en formatDate

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

En la función recojo el valor de la fecha en la variable fechaRango y la paso como valor a la siguiente función

```
function recorrerClientes() {

  var accesoClientes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Clientes");
  var calculoFila = accesoClientes.getDataRange();
  var ultimaFila = calculoFila.getLastRow();
  var facturaPorHoras = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('', 'Clientes' + '!V1:V' + ultimaFila);

  for (var j = 1; j <= ultimaFila; j++) {
    //Si el valor de V es mayor que 0,llamamos a la función comprobarFacturaPorHoras
    if (facturaPorHoras.values[j - 1] > 0) {
      var nombreCliente = accesoClientes.getRange(j, 2).getValue();
      var fechaRango = accesoClientes.getRange(j, 23).getValue();
      comprobarFacturaPorHoras(nombreCliente, j, fechaRango);
    }
  }
}
```

En la siguiente función realizo el siguiente código, pero me lanza una excepción al formatear la fecha:

```
function comprobarFacturaPorHoras(nombreCliente, filaCliente, fechaRango) {
 var fechaFormateada = Utilities.formatDate(fechaRango,"GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  Logger.log("La fecha a comparar: " + fechaFormateada);
}
```

En el logger me sale la fecha correcta, pero después me lanza este error:

**Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.**

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. A. Cedano ya explicó en su respuesta lo que significa el mensaje de error, pero el "origen" del problema está en el valor que se ha registrado en la hoja de cálculo. Por favor agrega a tu pregunta tanto el valor que se muestra en la celda como el que se muestra en la barra de fórmula así como la configuración regional de tu hoja de cálculo. Esto porque a la vista el valor podría parecer una fecha, pero la hoja de cálculo lo está interpretando como texto.. Ref. [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La Excepción:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the
> method signature for Utilities.formatDate.

Está indicando que los parámetros que pasas a `formatDate` no están respetando la firma el método, que requiere que el primer parámetro sea del tipo `Date`, [como indica la documentación](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parameters_25).

Para corregirlo, debes convertir el primer parámetro a fecha:

```
function comprobarFacturaPorHoras(nombreCliente, filaCliente, fechaRango) {
 var fechaFormateada = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(fechaRango),"GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  Logger.log("La fecha a comparar: " + fechaFormateada);
}
```

Comment: Además de lo que mencionas hay que considerar el valor que se ha escrito en la hoja de cálculo corresponda a un valor válido como parámetro de `Date`.